# passing local variable to subprocess popen running 'gnome-terminal -e' in python

Tags: python, bash, variables, subprocess, popen

my python script is calling another bash script (that receive arguments) and opening it in a new terminal (it may seem odd but i have my reasons).

I am trying to pass local python variable to popen but i am getting blank arguments in mybashscript.
what am i doing wrong?

code example:

```
var1="aaa"
var2="bbb"
var3="ccc"

subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "-e", "/home/mybashscript", var1, var2, var3])
```

I need var1, var2, and var3 to be the bash script arguments.

Comment: Does it work when you manually run `gnome-terminal -e /home/mybashscript aaa bbc ccc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var1="aaa"
var2="bbb"
var3="ccc"

subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "-e", "/home/mybashscript -"+var1+" -"+var2+" -"+var3])
```

or

```
var1="aaa"
var2="bbb"
var3="ccc"

subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "-e",
                 "/home/mybashscript %s %s %s" % (var1, var2, var3)])
```

Comment: the second option doesn't work. the first is missing " somewhere?

Comment: @Nlandau: the second code example had `]` in the wrong place, it should come *after* the string i.e., the intent is to create the command: `["gnome-terminal", "-e", "/home/mybashscript aaa bbb ccc"])`. Note: `xterm -e` option would work with your original command (`-e` consumes all following parameters in xterm's case and it consumes only one parameter in `gnome-terminal`'s case). Alternatively, you could have used `gnome-terminal -x` to pass the rest of the arguments to the command.

Comment: I checked and the second example works also as you said. Thanks again